# How to set an AutoMapper global configuration just for current user?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, automapper

**Introduction**:

I have an `Asp.Net MVC` project with `AutoMapper` and `IOC` (*StructureMap*) and every things works well.

I declared some `AutoMapper Profiles` and registered them by the `IOC` and finally use `IMappingEngine` in the contractor of some classes to use `AutoMapper` in them.

```
AutoMapper Version:   4.0.4
StructureMap Version: 4.2.0.402
```

---

**Issue:**

I want set a **global convert configuration** for all AutoMapper profiles based on the **timezone claim of the current user**.

> ### Rules of this AutoMapper convert configuration :
>
> - **Should** be a global configuration for all AutoMapper profiles
> - **Should** be some where in the project that every time the user send us a request we set it by the User timezone claim
> - **Should not** affects on AutoMapper configuration of other online users (it should not be a settings of the singleton objects of the
>     AutoMapper in IOC)

---

**What I did:**

I write the following configuration in the `OnAuthorization` method of a class inherited of `AuthorizeAttribute` and used this attribute on the `Controller` classes in my project:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class Mcv5AuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{  
    public Mcv5AuthorizeAttribute(): base(){}

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        var ct = filterContext.HttpContext;
        if (ct.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(conf => conf.CreateMap<DateTime, string>().ConvertUsing(new MyDateTimeConverter(ct.User.GetUserTimezoneId())));

            // Other codes
        }
   }
}
```

Also i thought to put the above code in the **`Base Controller`** or in the **`Controller Factory`**.

---

**My Questions:**

- Taking into account the described `IOC` in the project, dose `Mapper.Initialize` affect on `AutoMapper` configuration of other online users too?
- How I should write the mentioned `AutoMapper` convert config to comply with the above rules?
- Where is the better place to write it (**`Base Controller`**,**`Controller Factory`**, a custom **`AuthorizeAttribute`** or...)?

---

**Update:**

Really i want define some **[custom type converter in AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters)**. You can read it and see some `ITypeConverter` converters like `ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>` there. But I'm finding a way to parametric my `TypeConverter`s and pass some parameters to them dynamically in each request based on the **user's setting** in the way that they work **globally for all profiles** but be **limited in the current user scope**.

Maybe IOC can help me in this way. Do you have any idea about it?

Anyway I think if I register the converters by `Mapper.Initialize` it affects on other online users too because AutoMapper is defained as a singelton object by IOC. I am finding a way to comply with all of the mentioned rules together.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to map that requires the locale? This doesn't sound like a problem I would try to solve with `AutoMapper` and I use it everywhere.

Comment: @Kjata30, Many thing in a good project  can be customized based on user settings and some of them can be done while mapping one Model to a ViewModel. For example if you want map a saved UTC DateTime to a string and also change its timezone to the user timezone during mapping. So it is enough to pass the appropriate timezone setting of the user to the Mapping process.

Comment: In that example you should use automapper to create your target objects with the utc time then set the datetime's timezone afterwards. Automapper shouldnt be locale or timezone dependant.

Comment: @Paul, AutoMapper is a mapping helper. It created to map one object to another object and during this mapping multiple conditions and parameters and converters can be used. Sometimes the programmers do this works event if they map the objects manually then my scenario is a normal operation, not a very special and AutoMapper created to do it!

Comment: @RAM AutoMapper is not the place to convert UTC DateTimes to locale strings. DateTime actually has a ToString overload that does exactly this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Kjata30, My question is about define some **[custom type converter in AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters)**. You can read it and see `ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>` there. But I'm finding a way to define my `TypeConverter`s **globally & dynamically in each request** based on the **user's setting** and **limited in the current user scope**. But if i register them by `Mapper.Initialize` it affects on other online users too because AutoMapper is defained as a singelton object by IOC. I am finding a way to comply with all of the mentioned rules.

Comment: I understand the question that you think you need answered, but I'm also telling you that the solution to "map a saved UTC DateTime to a string and also change its timezone to the user timezone" is not best solved this way. However, if you're set on doing this with AutoMapper try using the `Map<>(object source, Action<IMappingOperationOptions> opts):TDestination` overload, which will allow you to use `BeforeMap(Action<object, object>)` and `AfterMap(Action<object, object>)` methods.

Comment: @Kjata30, But I think the best place to fill the `ViewModel` by the `Model` is in the _Auto Mapping Process_ else I should convert those properties manually in the `Controller`s or `View`s after automatic mapping process. So my question of you is why I should fill some properties of the `ViewModel` after `AutoMapper` process on it? Why I should write many extra codes in many places In the `UI` project in a big project when I can reach the target by some additional settings on `AutoMapper` and its features? What is the best solved this way that you think?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize should be called once per AppDomain. You can pass parameters per Map call, through Context.Items. You can check those parameters in your resolvers/converters. You can also use dependency injection to achieve the same thing by injecting per request helpers. The docs are [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dependency-injection).

Comment: Thank you, but may you edit your answer and add a sample code in it? I want prevent _pass parameters per Map_ Because the user settings are equal every where in the current request and some Automapper Profile needs them. So I want reduce repetitious codes and using dynamic parameters by `IOC` is the more interesting idea for me.